# Get form data inside form class.

Tags: django

Is there a better way to get data inside a form class?

```
from django import forms

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    subject = forms.CharField(required=True)
    message = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.Textarea)

    def send(self):
        self.data['data']['subject'] 
        self.data['data']['message']
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mean you need the values of the filled in form?

In your view, check if the form is valid using `form.is_valid()`; this populates `self.cleaned_data` containing your cleaned values. Using data isn't all that safe without validating it first.

so:

views.py:

```
if request.method == 'post':
    form = ContactForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
       form.send()
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    subject = forms.CharField(required=True)
    message = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.Textarea)

    def send(self):
        subject = self.cleaned_data['subject']
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering why I kept reading about cleaned_data but my form didn't have such an attribute.